# How can i use QnAMaker to provide random answers to same query

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I was thinking as bots have some generic questions like how are you ? may be i have around 10 answers which i would like Q&A maker to choose randomly not every time same answer.

or also questions like tell me a story

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> some generic questions like how are you ? may be i have around 10 answers which i would like Q&A maker to choose randomly not every time same answer.

To achieve this requirement, you can try this approach:

1) Add a QnA pair and use a special character (such as `|`) to split answers for question `how are you?`

[image]

2) Override the `RespondFromQnAMakerResultAsync` method, and split response and retrieve answer randomly in this method

```
protected override async Task RespondFromQnAMakerResultAsync(IDialogContext context, IMessageActivity message, QnAMakerResults result)
{
    // This will only be called if Answers isn't empty

    var response = result.Answers.First().Answer;
    var answersforhowareyou = response.Split('|');

    if (answersforhowareyou.Count() > 1)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int index = rnd.Next(answersforhowareyou.Count());

        response = answersforhowareyou[index];
    }

    await context.PostAsync(response);
}
```

***Test result:***

[image]

Comment: Thank you , for this custom solution idea