# node - botframework/QnAMaker multiple answers

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-qna-maker

How do I have multiple answers to same question?

I use Node and I'm pretty new to this, exampels?

This thread has an answer to my problem but its in C#
[How can i use QnAMaker to provide random answers to same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50971837/how-can-i-use-qnamaker-to-provide-random-answers-to-same-query/50981146)

Comment: This should be pretty easy, but are you using BotBuilder V3 or V4?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you've already got a handle on how to use the [botbuilder-cognitive services](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/11/17/qna-maker-node-js-bots/) package.

Just like in the C# version, you can override `respondFromQnAMakerResult()`. You can see in the [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/Node/lib/QnAMakerDialog.js) that you don't need to check if there are any answers because `respondFromQnAMakerResult()` is only called if there's at least one answer.

This is basically the solution from the other question translated into JavaScript:

```
basicQnAMakerDialog.respondFromQnAMakerResult = function(session, qnaMakerResult) {
    var msg = qnaMakerResult.answers[0].answer;
    var answersforhowareyou = msg.split('|');

    if (answersforhowareyou.count() > 1)
    {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * answersforhowareyou.length);
        msg = answersforhowareyou[index];
    }

    session.send(msg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have problem implementing this, see below

Answer (score -1):

Trying to implement this, errors as below

ReferenceError: answer is not defined
        at QnAMakerDialog.basicQnAMakerDialog.respondFromQnAMakerResult (D:\home\site\wwwroot\app.js:123:38)
        at QnAMakerDialog.invokeAnswer (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder-cognitiveservices\lib\QnAMakerDialog.js:76:22)
        at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder-cognitiveservices\lib\QnAMakerDialog.js:52:31
        at next (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\dialogs\IntentRecognizer.js:68:17)
        at IntentRecognizerSet.IntentRecognizer.filter (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\dialogs\IntentRecognizer.js:71:9)
        at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\dialogs\IntentRecognizer.js:20:31
        at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\dialogs\IntentRecognizerSet.js:80:17
        at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16
        at replenish (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:306:28)
        at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:326:29
        at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:44:16
        at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\dialogs\IntentRecognizerSet.js:72:21
        at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder-cognitiveservices\lib\QnAMakerRecognizer.js:52:21
        at Request._callback (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder-cognitiveservices\lib\QnAMakerRecognizer.js:107:25)
        at Request.self.callback (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
        at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)

Comment: I've fixed my typo

Comment: You should not use an answer to comment on another answer. You should use a comment on the answer for that.